# Ngrx store get user data after refresh page

Tags: angular, authentication, ngrx, store

I need get user data from db and put into store after refresh page. Now in Guard I get user id from local storage and dispatch action to get user data from db. It's safe? maybe I should do it in different way?

Answer (score 0):

It isn't save because when a user navigates to the page the first time, the local storage entry will be empty. It's probably better to read the params from the route.

Comment: I save user data after success login in local storage, so I can read id.